# method with the same name but different parameter

Tags: java, c#, class, overloading

I want to overload the method to avoid code duplication. How do I do this?

```
//Method 1 
    public Boolean func_e(Int32 item)
    {
        foreach (ItemUtility itemI in itemsUtilities)
        {
            if (itemI.item == item)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (itemI.item > item)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


//Method 2 
    public Boolean func_e(int item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsUtilities.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (itemsUtilities[i].item == item)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (itemsUtilities[i].item > item)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In this situation, I encounter with the Error , Error is:

**Type 'ClassName' already defines a member called 'contains' with the same parameter types**

Note : The code has migrated from Java to C #. One of the functions has an "int" input and another function is the "integer" (To accept null value)

Please can some one help. Thankful

Comment: An overloaded method needs to have *different* parameters.  Yours are the same.  Also, your methods appear to do the same thing anyway.  So what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Method1 uses a foreach, method 2 uses a for loop. What's the point of the two versions? Also, `int` and `Int32` are the same.

Comment: The code has migrated from Java to C #. One of the functions has an "int" input and another function is the "integer" (To accept null value)

Comment: I suggest you add that context into the question - it makes a lot more sense at that point.

Comment: @Basiijgarmm The equivalent of an `Integer` that can be null in C# is `int?` which is short for `Nullable<int>`.  `int` is just an alias for `Int32` which is the value type.

Comment: @juharr , Thanks for your guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the important part of the question:

> The code has migrated from Java to C #. One of the functions has an "int" input and another function is the "integer" (To accept null value)

There's no direct equivalent of `java.lang.Integer` in .NET, but in order to allow null values, you would use `int?` (a synonym for `Nullable<int>`). Just using `int` and `Int32` doesn't work, because they're the same type.

So you can have:

```
// Names changed to be more idiomatic, though still not great
public bool FuncE(int item)
{
    ...
}

public bool FuncE(int? item)
{
    ...
}
```

All that said, I strongly suspect you can refactor the code to just a single method accepting `int?`, and quite possibly do it in a single expression using LINQ. It's slightly hard to tell what you're trying to achieve with the `int?` parameter though.